# What was the name and origin of this security software?

Tags: software, windows-98

I am trying to find a free software for security, that I downloaded for tracing someone attached to my computer.  I remember using this on my Windows 98 system.  You could see on a map where the connection was coming from and you could search their info on Who Is right from the app.  I would really like to find something comparable for Windows 10.  The app was very user-friendly for a newbie.

Comment: You could try wireshark - tells you which computers are connected to your PC and which computers your PC is connected to.  Not the easiest tool to use but once you get the hang of it, it is the most brilliant tool for analyzing comms.  I can't see how a PC can figure out who is connected.  Anyone can use any machine, as long as they have a login to your machine, they can connect.  Doesn't tell you who they are: just which IP address they are connecting from.

Comment: Your follow-up question, "what software is like this program, but for Windows 10?" (obviously including a description of the features like yours here) should be posted on [softwarerecs.se], not here.

Comment: I feel like ZoneAlarm was the predominant thing for Windows 98, albeit that it apparently didn't appear until 2000. So possibly false memory syndrome. But if it was that then I think it's still actively developed for modern Windows.

Comment: @Tommy - the "first release" on the wikipedia page for ZoneAlarm is clearly wrong, as it suggests that 2.0.something was the first released version, but if you look on the ZoneAlarm site's Free Firewall release history, it goes back to 1.5.20, although they don't give dates for anything older than 2.1. Also: 1.5.21 fixed an "incompatibility" with Eudora.  Now that's a name from the past. :)

Comment: @Jules you're right; the oldest archived copy of zonelabs.com shows they were already on 1.7 by 1999; an archived whitepaper on ZoneAlarm suggests the company itself is from 1997 and that the software initially supported Windows 95 as well as 98 ( https://web.archive.org/web/19991128174439/http://www2.zonelabs.com:80/pdf/WP_ZoneAlarm.pdf ). So very much more correlated with Windows 98 than my lazy check suggested.

Comment: I am pretty sure it wasn't Zone Alarm.  It was after 2001  though.  It was some free software i found somewhere and downloaded.  I was running Norton antivirus and with this detection software i found that Norton was routing traffic through my computer.  I contacted them and asked them why (x) company was being routed through my computer and they said they were not at liberty to discuss the business of (x) company.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am right with how you describe it I remember the app.  It was called TraceRoute and there are plenty of modern equivalents either online or for download which are easily found on Google using the TraceRoute name as a search.